# Why is window.setTimeout returning with an error?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am coding a notes page for my classmates in school, and I am trying to do a little pop-out box for each subject. As the css transition doesn't work for the position attribute, I tried using javascript and setTimeout. For some reason, the code `window.setTimeout(box.style.position = 'absolute', 1000);` isn't working and returning error "Uncaught ReferenceError: absolute is not defined". Can someone please tell me what is causing this error?

Thanks!

Comment: `setTimeout` accepts a function as the first argument: `window.setTimeout(()=>{box.style.position = 'absolute'}, 1000);`

Comment: first argument to `setTimeout` should be a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) takes a function reference, not plain JavaScript code. Also, because `setTimeout()` is a method of the Global `window` object, you can omit `window.` and just call `setTimeout()` directly.

Make your code this:

```
setTimeout(function(){box.style.position = 'absolute'}, 1000);
```

Or this:

```
function foo(){
  box.style.position = 'absolute'
}
setTimeout(foo, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you! I like doing web design and stuff like that, but I'm pretty new to JavaScript.

Comment: @TylerSilberman You're welcome. Don't forget to mark this as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`window.setTimeout` accepts either a function or a string to be evaluated as the first argument. Since `box.style.position = 'absolute'` evaluates to `'absolute'`, it tries to execute that as code, which throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: absolute is not defined`. The solution is to pass a function to be executed instead.

```
window.setTimeout(()=>{box.style.position = 'absolute'}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ box.style.position = 'absolute'; }, 1000);
```

Please use this